# Xamarin Android BottomNavigationView invisible when Rotation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hello I have this app where I need the bottomTabBar to disappear when device is rotated. The Problem is that every time I rotate it doesn't work the way I want.

here is my code:

```
 public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        if (_bottomNavigationView == null)
            _bottomNavigationView = bottomView;

        if (bottomViewHeight == 0)
            bottomViewHeight = bottomView.LayoutParameters.Height;
        _IShellAppearanceElement = appearance;

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

        if (rotation == DisplayRotation.Rotation270 || rotation == DisplayRotation.Rotation90)
        {
            var parameters = bottomView.LayoutParameters;
            parameters.Height = 0;
            bottomView.LayoutParameters = parameters;
            bottomView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            bottomView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, -1);
        }
        else
        {
            bottomView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            var parameters = bottomView.LayoutParameters;
            parameters.Height = 200;
            bottomView.LayoutParameters = parameters;
            bottomView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 100);
        }
    }
```

**This is Portrait mode**

[image: this is portrait mode]

**This is landscape mode**
[image]

[image]
**this is back to portrait mode**

Comment: What is GlobalScreenSizeApp ?

Comment: its a propriety that gets the height and other parameters from the app. the NavigationBarHeight  its the same as `Resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");` .How can I make Sure? I debugged and every time the orientations changes the method is called.

Comment: when I tried to run your code I hit that GlobalScreenSizeApp is not defined, it's better to give a working code when asking the community. Also I cannot reproduce, could you attach a reproduction repo? Is your solution supposed to update dynamically whenever the orientation changed?

Comment: @Cfun it is supposed to update, and I can't attach the repo in here because of company rules. I'll change the question to add the  GlobalScreenSizeApp variable

Comment: I meant by repo a new empty project that reproduce this specific issue only, it doesn't need to contain any other code, only the relevant (could be dummy) code that highlight the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your implementation, and `SetAppearance` was never called when I rotate the screen. It was only called when the view is changed (for example, I click on a tab or something). I would double check if in your case the method is really called every time you change screen orientation, like you said.

On the other hand, by overriding `OnConfigurationChanged` method I was able to get your desired behavior.
Not sure how the rest of your code looks like, but you can do something like I did.
In `MainActivity` I added `static public BottomNavigationView bv;` and implementation of `OnConfigurationChanged`:

```
        public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (bv != null)
            {
                if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
                { 
                    var parameters = bv.LayoutParameters;
                    parameters.Height = 0;
                    bv.LayoutParameters = parameters;
                    bv.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                    bv.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, -1);
                }
                else
                { 
                    bv.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    var parameters = bv.LayoutParameters;
                    parameters.Height = 200;
                    bv.LayoutParameters = parameters;
                    bv.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 100);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then, in other file where I implmented IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker (I guess you have that somewhere):

```
        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            //Some other code if necessary

            if (MainActivity.bv == null)
                MainActivity.bv = bottomView;

            //Some other code if necessary
        }
```

I'm not sure what is `_bottomNavigationView` in your case and how you use it, but I guess you can do something similar like I did with `bv`.

Comment: Thanks to @admm I was abble to solve my problem. Thank you!